# Date autofill increments year instead of day

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, date

Earlier, when I had dates in a column like:

```
Monday, 21 April, 2014
Tuesday, 22 April, 2014
```

and I extended the last cell to lower cells I could expect them to be filled with following days:

```
Wednesday, 23 April, 2014
Thursday, 24 April, 2014
```

but now I get:

```
Tuesday, 22 April, 2015
Tuesday, 22 April, 2016
```

Why is that? All cells in column are in date format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured it out. For unknown reason this particular date format has been changed in Google Sheets, instead of:

```
Monday, 21 April, 2014
```

now it is:

```
Monday, April 21, 2014
```

so that only the second one works now and the previous one isn't recognized as a pattern any more.

Comment: locale might be the reason, earlier I've probably used other English than American English - formatting had nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

If formatted as text at data entry, those are the results, if formatted as a date (say dddd, dd mmm, yyyy) the appearance will be the same but the date will increment by a day at a time.

Answer (score 1):

- Right click and go to format cell.
- Under category choose Date and format as 31.dec.1999.
  key in your date as for example : 12/31/99 and press enter.
- The date will be automatically changed to given format of 31.Dec.1999.
- Then drag the button you can see the date change and not the year.